# Javascript setting variable to result or nothing

Tags: javascript, if-statement, bit-manipulation

See javascript comments

```
var SearchResult = {
    googleApiKey: "",
    googleUrl: "https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key={key}&country={country}&q={query}&alt=atom",
    country: "UK"
    Query: function( args )
    {     
        // Is there a way to do this in a less messy way?
        args.googleApiKey ? : this.googleApiKey = args.googleApiKey : null;
        args.country? : this.country = args.country: null;
    }
}
```

Basically, if someone supplies a new value for my object properties, I want it to set it, otherwise just continue using the default values supplied.

I'm aware of bitwise operators being good for option selecting but I don't know how I would port that into javascript?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You mean `args.googleApiKey= this.googleApiKey ? this.googleApiKey : null;` or use || as shown in the answers below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript you can use the following:

```
// thingYouWantToSet = possiblyUndefinedValue || defaultValue;
this.googleApiKey = args.googleApiKey || '';
```

The caveat to using this is that if the first value is a zero or empty string, you will end up using the default value, which may not be what you intend. e.g.

```
var example = '';
var result = example || 'default';
```

Although example is set, you will end up with the 'default' string. If this causes issues for you, switch to:

```
(typeof args.googleApiKey === 'undefined') 
    ? this.googleApiKey = 'default'
    : this.googleApiKey = args.googleApiKey;
```

You could make this cleaner using a helper function if you are repeating yourself a lot.

```
var mergedSetting = function (setting, default) {
    return (typeof setting === 'undefined') ? default : setting;
}

this.googleApiKey = mergedSetting(args.googleApiKey, 'default value');
```

Comment: That second one is exactly what I intend :)... so if I return null, it will set the variable to null.. what I need to do is:... this.googleApiKey = args.googleApiKey || this.googleApiKey.... Sound right? or does returning null just return the default value?

Comment: `this.googleApiKey = args.googleApiKey || this.googleApiKey;` will leave it at its current value if `args.googleApiKey` is `undefined, null, false, 0 or ''`. If `this.googleApiKey` has been updated to `Hello World`, it would remain `Hello World`. If you want to revert it to a default value, supply that in the code like this: `this.googleApiKey = args.googleApiKey || '';`

Comment: Thanks. That will do it :)

Answer (score 4):

```
args.googleApiKey = args.googleApiKey || this.googleApiKey;
args.country = args.country || this.country;
```

Not sure I understood your question;

Comment: +1 You beat me to it. In the OP's case, I think they want to set `this.googleApiKey` as that is what is being set in the question.

Comment: this.googleApiKey = args.googleApiKey || this.googleApiKey ... Can it also be this.googleApiKey = args.googleApiKey || null ... or will this make this.googleApiKey = null?

Comment: you are right this will make this.googleApiKey = null (Note, not in case if args.googleApiKey is one of these: 0, '', false, undefined)